# Is "with" used correctly here?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say I received an 8/10 grade for my thesis. In the sentence

"I successfully defended my MSc thesis with an 8/10 grade,"

does "with" refer to the thesis defence or the thesis itself?

Comment: it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, **with** more logically refers to the thesis defence—but it still makes the sentence semantically awkward.

You *didn't* defend your thesis with an 8/10 grade. That would be the equivalent of saying:

> I used an 8/10 grade in the defence of my thesis.

(You could argue that the sentence means you defended your thesis which *already had* an 8/10 grade—but that wouldn't make sense either because if it already had a grade, you wouldn't need to defend it in the first place.)

It would be more appropriate to rephrase your example sentence.

Something like:

> I successfully defended my thesis and received an 8/10 grade.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it means either of the options you specify. Rather, "with" connects your grade to your thesis. In other words, "with" refers to "8/10 grade."

Answer (score -1):

Must be Brazil or another country that grades out of 10.

Sure, you can say that. You can also say; I got or received or was given a grade of 8/10.

Bear in mind that in English-speaking countries, grades are absolute. You don't receive a grade between two numbers. Also, generally, grades are not out of ten. When a numbering system is used for grading, it is usually out of 100.

So you might be better off saying, I received a grade in the highest range (80-100). That is one way to localize the expression.

Also, bear in mind, that in English-speaking countries, Phd's are defended. Master's degrees are usually awarded or earned.

In English, you are awarded a degree, you earn a degree and you receive a grade.

- I got (or received or was awarded or earned) my Master's with a top grade in the 80-100 range (degrees in X are awarded in a range)

(Please note, these are general comments re usage, not a be-all, end-all guide.)

Comment: "in English-speaking countries, grades are absolute. You don't receive a grade between two numbers. Also, generally, grades are not out of ten. When a numbering system is used for grading, it is usually out of 100." You would not write that if you had been to school in Britain.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you get grades like this in Britain: 8 to 10?  https://www.classbase.com/Countries/united-kingdom/Grading-System  Are grades given in a range? So, I missed it, apparently, it's 0 to 70, right? And this: http://www.iupui.edu/~british/British_Studies/grading.html

Comment: If you got 72 UK grade that equates (just) to an A American grade. When I was at school, we got marks out of 10 for class work. Above 8 was good, 6 or 7 was OK, less than 6, do it again.

Comment: OK, 8 out of 10. Is that how you mark in the UK? The only place I know with 10 as the highest mark is Brazil. I actually mixed this up with France, where grades are out of 20 and they do give distinctions based on a range: like 18 out of 20 written as: 18/20 but means 18 to 20. Whence my inter-lingual confusion. Sometimes my marbles roll around between slots. :) Yes, I saw that in the UK, 70 is the top mark in some schools.

Comment: I did an edit; in the UK a 'mark' of '8/10' is said as 'eight out of ten'. It's like a fraction. You could have 16/20 or 80/100 or 40/50. Or whatever. You make the denominator big enough to accommodate the precision you need.

Comment: I have already understood what you said. It was not necessary to repeat it. I acknowledged. Have you understood what I said?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80250/discussion-between-michael-harvey-and-lambie).

Comment: Not worth it to me.